# Insert..Select into InnoDB table with commit after each insert?

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, insert, innodb

I just finished creating a new partitioned table to replace an old, non-partitioned table (renamed for safekeeping). I copied the newest data from the old table into the new table at the time I created it, but I still have roughly half the data left to copy over. The problem is, it's a live web service getting hammered nonstop, and every time I try to copy a chunk over via INSERT..SELECT, it insists on doing it as an atomic transaction (which consumes all the server's resources, slows everything to a crawl, and probably pushes the server dangerously close to running out of physical resources).

Just to be clear: OldTable is MyISAM. NewTable is InnoDB and partitioned by range on its primary key 'a'. Both tables have identical field names. The fields themselves aren't identical, but where they differ, the fields in NewTable are bigger.

The query that's causing problems looks like:

```
INSERT INTO NewTable (a,b,c,d,e,f,g) 
SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,g 
FROM OldTable 
WHERE a > 300000000 AND a <= 400000000
order by a
```

What I'd like for it to do: either commit after each insert, or just dispense with transactional integrity entirely and allow dirty reads to happen if they happen.

Locking NewTable (beyond possibly the one single row being inserted) is unacceptable. Locking OldTable is fine, because nothing else is using it anymore, anyway (besides the SQL to copy it to the new table, of course).

Also, is there a way to tell MySQL to do it at the lowest possible priority, and only work on the task in its (relative) free time?

Comment: If you want to commit RBAR (Row By Agonizing Row), then you need a cursor.

Comment: Is there any middle ground compromise? Like maybe having MySQL commit every hundred or thousand rows? It doesn't LITERALLY have to be committed after a single row... I just don't want to wait for it to insist on trying to do a million rows in a single gulp, and there are too many total rows that still have to be moved to do them in chunks smaller than a million if I'm copying it from a text editor and pasting it into MySQL's commandline client.

Comment: I've yet to encounter SQL syntax that allows you to specify an arbitrary number for bulk insertion/updating.

Comment: Can't you just reduce the amount of rows you're copying at a time?

Comment: Well, I could... I was just hoping there was a more elegant solution natively supported via SQL itself. Sigh. One of these days, I'm going to have to re-learn Perl so I won't have to build jarfiles and upload them to the server to do one-off database maintenance tasks like this. Using Java is kind of like leasing a backhoe to transplant a marigold ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to reducing the number of rows being inserted at a time, try increasing the value of `bulk_insert_buffer_size` system variable to something more appropriate for your case? The default value is 8MB.